# How can I install install windows on lenovo yoga 920?

Tags: windows, installation, lenovo-laptop

I've got an lenovo yoga 920 dualboot with alpine linux and windows. Now windows thinks that I've changed something and wants my bitlocker recorvery key which I don't have (and no, it's not on my microsoft account).

So I though I should reinstall windows. I download windows from microsofts site, but the yoga can't boot from the USB. After some investigation I figure out that microsofts install disc is using NTFS and the yoga will only boot from FAT32.

I create a FAT32 usb drive, copy all files from the downloaded windows install iso to that drive. And reboot, the windows install program starts but fails to load install.wim. Turns out the install.wim is bigger that the allowed filesize for a file on a FAT32 drive.

I tested with exFAT, but the yoga won't find it as a boot option.

How can I install install windows?

Comment: You can either use the Media Creation Tool or Rufus, but the methods you have used so far, will not work.  Your device absolutely should be able to boot from a USB removable drive.

Comment: My device can boot from USB, not just from an NTFS formated USB. Is media creation tool or rufus able to create FAT usb?

Comment: Either one of those tools are the proper tool

Comment: You can get the Lenovo USB Recovery Key. These work for sure (I have used them). Contact Lenovo Support for the site for your machine to download and make the bootable Recovery Key.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a USB memory with two partitions, the first an FAT32 that contains all files and folder except sources/ AND sources/boot.wim and then another NTFS partition with the rest of the sources/ folder.